# How do I order my images in my photosNSMutable array by "created_time" and get my collection view to display them accordingly?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsmutablearray, uicollectionview

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Fashun
//
//  Created by Alex Macleod on 20/10/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Macleod. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var collectionView: UICollectionView?

var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()
var accessToken: NSString! = "14128167.52d0add.2fbff9669d9141099597cbb8d67764a4"
var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults!
let colorWheel = ColorWheel()
var photoCount: Int! = 0
let photos = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

//    userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
//    self.accessToken = userDefaults!.objectForKey("accessToken") as NSString
//    println(self.accessToken)

//        instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty = "Hello World"
//        var accessToken : NSString? = NSString(instanceOfCustomObject.accessToken)
//        println(accessToken)
//        instanceOfCustomObject.authorize()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 124, height: 124)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self
    collectionView!.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

    getData()
//    imageCount()

}

    func getData() -> Void {

        let tuulavintageUrl = NSURL(string:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/7522782/media/recent/?access_token=\(self.accessToken)")
        let wendyslookbookUrl = NSURL(string:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/14454619/media/recent/?access_token=\(self.accessToken)")

//        let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
//        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(baseUrl!, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            //            var urlContents = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
            //            println(urlContents)

            let tuulavintageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: tuulavintageUrl!)
            let wendyslookbookData = NSData(contentsOfURL: wendyslookbookUrl!)

            if (tuulavintageData != nil) & (wendyslookbookData != nil) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

                    let tuulavintageDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(tuulavintageData!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
                    let wendyslookbookDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(wendyslookbookData!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary
//                    println(tuulavintageDictionary)
                    var tuulavintageImageResponse = tuulavintageDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray
                    var tuulavintageTimeResponse = tuulavintageDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.created_time") as NSArray
//                    println(tuulavintageTimeResponse)
                    var wendyslookbookImageResponse = wendyslookbookDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.images.standard_resolution.url") as NSArray
                    var wendyslookbookTimeResponse = wendyslookbookDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.created_time") as NSArray
                    println(wendyslookbookTimeResponse)

                    for imageUrls in tuulavintageImageResponse {

                        var imageUrlsAsStrings: NSString = imageUrls as NSString
                        var imageAsNsurls = NSURL(string: imageUrlsAsStrings)

                        var err: NSError?
                        var imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageAsNsurls!,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
                        self.photos.addObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!)
//                        println(self.photos)

                    }

                    for imageUrls in wendyslookbookImageResponse {

                        var imageUrlsAsStrings: NSString = imageUrls as NSString
                        var imageAsNsurls = NSURL(string: imageUrlsAsStrings)

                        var err: NSError?
                        var imageData :NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageAsNsurls!,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)!
                        self.photos.addObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!)
//                        println(self.photos)

                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        self.photoCount = tuulavintageImageResponse.count + wendyslookbookImageResponse.count as Int

                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                    })
                })

            } else {

                let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Something went wrong get a better phone you pleb!", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)
                let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)

                self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    //Stop refresh animation

                })
            }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photoCount
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as Cell
    //                println(photos)
    //            cell.textLabel.text = "Text"
        cell.imageView.image = photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage
    //    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = colorWheel.randomColor()

        return cell
    }
}
```

As you can see I am making a call to instagram's API for their 20 most recent pictures for two separate users "tuulavintage" and "wendyslookbook". I then parse the data for the imageUrls, put them into two separate for in loops where I take those imageUrls and change them to UIImages and put them inside the "let photos = NSMutableArray()". Then I add the UIimages to my collection view cell "cell.imageView.image = photos.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage"

I also count my parsed NSdictionary response like so "self.photoCount = tuulavintageImageResponse.count + wendyslookbookImageResponse.count as Int". So I can tell my collection view how many cells to make

You can also see here (inside the global main que)
"var tuulavintageTimeResponse = tuulavintageDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.created_time") as NSArray"

and here

"var wendyslookbookTimeResponse = wendyslookbookDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data.created_time") as NSArray"

I parse my NSDictionary response to retrieve an array of unixtimecode for each image but they aren't connected.

My question is how to I order these photos being displayed in my collection view by the time they were posted using the unixtimecode I can retrieve? I have a feeling I need to match up the UIimage's with their specific timecode, then somehow tell my collection view to order them by unixtime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t82qcgw7lcde7tx/Fashun.zip?dl=0 
Here is a link to my project if anyone dares look at my hideous code.

Comment: create your own object then that will have 2 properties, an UIImage and the TimeStamp. And now your arrays won't just store the UIImage, it will store this new Class  that will have this 2 properties for your needs :)

Comment: oh man how do I do that? "create my own object" "new Class" does that me I have to create a new swift file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you dont have to create a file but is good practice to keep things nice and neat.

try either in the same controller file but outside of your controller definition or inside your new Swift file.

```
class IGPhotoContainer  {

   var image: UIImage!
   var timestamp: String = ""   

   //Your constructor can be like this 
   init() {

   }

   //or overload it with 2 params for your convenience. 
   init(newimage: UIImage, newtime: String){

      this.image = newimage
      this.timestamp = newtime

   }

}
```

if you do it in a seperate File remember to add this line of code at the beginning of your new file.

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, I will give the photoMatrix another go and then do the above. Will get back to you when I hit that inevitable always looming brick wall.

Comment: @alemac852  just a quick side note, since you want to compare timestamps I recommend you use Float/Double types instead of String... that was my mistake there.

Comment: So I've given up on the photoMatrix. I made the class above in a separate swift file. How do I tell my collection view to order the photos by the time? I'm so lost...

Comment: How can I contact you Steven Hernandez. I have a proposal that might be of interest to you.

Comment: I noticed you are into making games for IOS. It just so happens I am a sound engineer/ sound designer/ music producer, and have made sounds for Apps before. Now considering the fact that you clearly know what your talking about when it comes to coding/swift. Would you be interested in helping me with my current project and in return I'll do sounds/music for your upcoming games?

Comment: @alemac852 sounds interesting, send me an email so we can talk. email is at my comment above